# Google Analytics: Track events per user per session

Tags: c#, mobile, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I set up google analytics for an (unity) mobile app and everything works fine so far. Now I'm starting to look into how to track different user interactions and am not really sure what's the best way to achieve what I want, which is:

- track how often a user does something (e.g. click a certain button) per session e.g. to determine the average usage of certain content elements per user per session

I'm currently just logging an event whenever the interaction is done (with a value of 1). Is there a way to get the count each event was send per user per session via a filter or would I need to count them within my code and send an event with the explicit value (e.g. `LogEvent("Interaction", "StartButtonClicked", label, count)`)? What is the most common way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to set a value to keep track of the number of events. The events report already aggregates the number of each event for you.

Comment: And then I could filter the total for single user and session or an average per session?